# How to get html table values from multiple columns with single checkbox and submit to servlet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I have html data table. I want to get values from multiple columns with single checkbox and when click on submit button values should go to servlet. Please help how to do this?

```
function refile(){
    $('#resend').click(function() {
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            var messagePayload =  $('#'+id).val();
            var messageType =  $('#msgType'+id).val();

            alert("Payload Alert:"+ messagePayload);
            alert("MessageType Alert:"+ messageType);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/InterfaceMonitoring/ResendServlet",
                data: {
                    messagePayload:messagePayload,
                    messageType:messageType
                }
            });
        });
    });
}


<c:otherwise>
    <c:forEach items="${msgs}" var="msg" varStatus="count">
        <tr id="check">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id ="payloadMsg${count.index}" name="payload" value="${msg.messagePayload}">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${msg.dob}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>${msg.name}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div class="accordion">
                    <h3>Payload</h3>
                    <div id="payloadMsg${count.index}">${msg.messagePayload}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div id="msgType${count.index}">${msg.messageType}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:otherwise>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question . . . what do you mean by `get values from multiple columns with single checkbox`?

Comment: Talemyn - I want to extract values from two cloumns (messagepayload and messagetype) using one check box and hit on submit button. In javascript I have to call both the values and post to servlet. Plz help.

Comment: Talemyn - you got any idea???

Comment: Jaagr looked like he had something good going, so I was letting you two work on that.   :)  Give me a few minutes and I can type up an idea that I had.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you try to get `messageType`.

Since you're using the ID of the input element, and prefixing it with `#msgType` it results in `#msgTypepayloadMsgX` so that element will never be found.

And since it's a DIV you're looking for you should use `.html()` to get the content.

Try adding `data-index="${count.index}"` to each `input[checkbox]` and get it in the script using `$(selector).data('index')` so that you can query for `$('#msgType' + index)`

And you should not make an ajax request for each row. Instead store the payloadMessage and messageType in an object and send it all to the backend at once, after iterating all rows.

An example could be:

Javascript

```
function refile(){
    $('#resend').click(function() {
        var payloads = [];

        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                index = $this.data('index'),
                $type = $('#msgType' + index);

            payloads.push({
                messageType: $type.html(),
                messagePayload: $this.val()
            });
        });

        if (payloads.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/InterfaceMonitoring/ResendServlet',
            data: {
                'payload': payloads
            }
        });
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<tr id="check">
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="payloadMsg${count.index}" data-index="${count.index}" name="payload" value="${msg.messagePayload}"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>${msg.dob}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>${msg.name}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div class="accordion">
            <h3>Payload</h3>
            <!-- Note that this ID is conflicting with the input#payloadMsg${count.index} -->
            <div id="payloadMsg${count.index}">${msg.messagePayload}</div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <div id="msgType${count.index}">${msg.messageType}</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Jaagr - Thanks you, let me try now. I will get back you. My basic requirement is here I want to extract values from two cloumns (messagepayload and messagetype) using one check box and hit on submit button. In javascript I have to call both the values and post to servlet.

Comment: I'm not really following you about what you want to achieve. Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/JeR3k/

Comment: Jaagr - I am getting null on servlet.I called it in servlet like below. Please suggest.                                            String payload = request.getParameter("payload");
 System.out.println("Got it: " + payload);

Comment: Jaagr - My problem is: I have created one html table that has many columns,I pull the data from database using servlets and publish in the table. Now I want to extract xml data from one column and message type from other column in table. Because user want to refile that xml message if any case timeout error or business request. To implement that logic I created check box and send button on page, so user simply click on send button, then backend message should create as webservice and ready for consume by other class. This is called resending data into original queue. Please help.

Comment: Since the data is already available on webpage table columns, I want to implement resend data logic. i.e. when user simply click on "send/resend" button by selecting checkbox xml data should create as webservice data and make it ready for consume by original class (i.e.actual application will consume that message). Your help much appreciated since it is pending long time my end.

Comment: Use Chrome DevTools (or an equivalent for the browser you are using) to check out the ajax request that is being made. There you will see the request/response data. I need a bit more information about what's going on to be able to help you. Did you look at my [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JeR3k/)? If so, is that what you want?

Comment: Jaagr - I saw ur jsfiddle example. I want to get both xml data and message type then send them to backend (assume servlet), there I have to expose that xml data into webservice based on message type condition. On page when i select checkbox and click send button both values should go to backend. If you still not clear my question please send me your mail id i can send you screenshots that I am working. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Post your e-mail address.

Comment: Jaagr - here my email address "ashok.ashokkumaraak@gmail.com"

Comment: send me test mail, i can send files.

Comment: Jaagr - can you send mail?

Answer (score 0):

So, from what I've seen, on the front-end, at least, your code **SHOULD** work, but you've made it *REALLY* complex. . . . more complicated than you need it to be, I think.  Again, while it should work, simplifying it will mean that there are much fewer places in the code where something could go wrong.

I think the best way to do this is make it easy on yourself:

1. flag the `<div>` elements that you want to retrieve with a `class` value that you can use to get their values (rather than relying on the unique IDs)
2. make the "unique" identifier of the message at the highest level in the table as you can (in this case, the `<tr>`
3. simplify your HTML attributes . . . you've got a lot of duplicate data and excess identifiers in your table structure. Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<c:otherwise>
    <c:forEach items="${msgs}" var="msg" varStatus="count">
        <tr id="payloadMsg${count.index}">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="payload">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="msg-dob">${msg.dob}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="msg-name">${msg.name}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div class="accordion">
                    <h3>Payload</h3>
                    <div class="msg-payload">${msg.messagePayload}</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <div class="msg-type">${msg.messageType}</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</c:otherwise>
```

Once you've set that up, you have a much more simple structure, with all of the values that you could ever need, clearly identified.  Now, you can pretty easily you can pretty easily get to the values that you need, using jQuery . . . just update your existing code to be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#resend').click(function() {
        $("input:checked").each(function () {
            var currRow = $(this).closest("tr");
            var currPayload = currRow.find(".msg-payload").text();
            var currType = currRow.find(".msg-type").text();

            alert("Payload Alert:"+ currPayload );
            alert("MessageType Alert:"+ currType );

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/InterfaceMonitoring/ResendServlet",
                data: {
                    messagePayload: currPayload,
                    messageType: currType
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** You were using `.val()` instead of `.text()` to retrieve the text in the "type" `<div>` . . . `.val()` is only used with input elements.

Not knowing what you are doing on the back-end with this data, I can't really help you make sure that it is storing it correctly, but removing the reliance on the indexes to find the data that you want, should help simplify your logic a lot.

Also, if you ever want any other data from the row, you can capture it pretty easily now . . . for example:

```
var currMsg = currRow.attr("id");
var currDOB = currRow.find(".msg-dob").text();
var currName = currRow.find(".msg-name").text();
```

. . . after you have set the `currRow` value in your code, of course.   :)

So, give that a try and see how things go.  On the front-end, you should be good with this, at that point, you would need to just focus on the back-end and make sure that everything is working there.

Comment: Talemyn - I updated code as you suggested, but I am not getting values  in alert window. Is something missing?

Comment: Talemyn - Two issues here. 1). Values are not coming in alert windows 2)Each time when I select row using checkbox and click send button the alerts count is increasing. Ex: I click first time it shows alert one time and when I select rwo second time alert showing two times, it is increasing every time

Comment: alert("Payload Alert:"+ currPayload );
alert("MessageType Alert:"+ currType ); Values are not coming, just showing names, no values. And each time I click on button alerts count increasing

Comment: Prepend the selectors with a dot (.) since they are classes. So currRow.find('.msg-type').text()

Comment: Jaagr - Great, thank you very much. I am getting values now. But why am I getting each time many alert windows? Ex: If I select one row and click submit button first time I am not getting any alert value, so again I click on button I am getting values. After that each time I select row and click button the alerts count increasing i.e. same alert window populating many times (Ex: 1 time click 2 alert windows coming, 2nd time hit 3 times showing, 3rd time click 4 times showing), why?. It should show only one message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Implement the JS in my answer to collect all payloads to one object. Update it with your new HTML and selectors from this answer.

Comment: 1) Thanks to @Jaagr for catching the selector typo . . . I do that in my code all the time.  Drives me crazy.  :)   2) Sorry for the delay in response . . . been a busy few days.  3) How are you calling the function `refile()`?  The way that this is set up, it should only ever be called once, to bind the `click` event to the `resend` button.  I'm updating my code to use `$(document).ready()` instead of `refile(){`.  Give that a try (don't forget to change `}` to `});` at the bottom).

Comment: @user3311215 - I was looking at your last big comment again and what you are describing sounds like you are calling `refile()` from the `onclick` attribute of the button. Since `refile()` has code in it to bind the alert logic to the click event, it would not show anything the 1st time that you clicked it (that click would bind the event). The 2nd time you clicked it, the bound event would fire once and you would bind the event again. The 3rd time, two bound events would fire and you would bind the event again, etc. If I am right, make the change that I noted above and remove the `onclick`.

Comment: The problem i found is my resend button is inside AJAX body html, it is causing problem while clicking resend button and behaving strange. I removed from AJAX body and placed in different jsp. It is working fine now. At this moment I am not sure why it is not working inside AJAX body. So far I am OK to place at other jsp.

Comment: @user3311215 - At this point, I would take what you have working here and start a new question with the new issue. Need to try to keep each questions to one topic.   ;)

Comment: Just change the `input` attribute `type="checkbox"` to `type="radio"`.  That will mean that they can only check one row at a time, though.

Comment: It should, since they both use `checked`.  Did you try it?   :D

Comment: Thank you Talemyn, its working fine with same JS for both checkbox and radio buttons.

Comment: Talemyn - I need one more help. As you know I am getting xml data from database and publish on webpage. But one of the tag value in the xml on webpage is different than database. Can you please suggest how can make exact data? Ex: On webpage in my xml tag value was present "^~\&|", but it should be "^~\&amp;|". Why on webpage it is showing "&" instead of "&amp;". I verified my servlet class, I am getting correct value in servlet, only problem on webpage. Please suggest.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this up as a new question on the site, if you can't find an existing question about it out there (for example, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524416/can-i-escape-html-entities-in-xml-so-that-they-are-displayed-literally-on-a-web/7524452#7524452 ).  You'll get a lot more help making it a question than asking it in the comments of an answer.   :)

Comment: talemyn - One more thing plz. As you know I am sending data to servlet from webpage. It is working for me fine in my local system and other QA server as well. But if any new user (or multiple users) try to send message by clicking send button, message not coming to servlet. It looks servlet not at all calling. But Javascript alerts showing the message without any issue. On the QA server I chnage my AJAX POST Url according to QA server (I mean changed host and port names). Why data is not coming to servlet when multiple users or other user on QA server? Please suggest.

Comment: LOL . . . that's a big question.  :)  Again, I'd suggest posting it up in it's own thread with as much information as you can provide about the situation.  I'm not sure that I'm going to be able to help as much on this one either, since it's a little out of the realm of my expertise.   :)